# Middleware Next Route in Node Express App Not Fired

Tags: node.js, express

I am using middleware to invoke the next route but for some reason it is not getting called. Here is the code:

```
app.get('/foo',function(req,res,next){

  console.log('first route')
  next('route')

},function(req,res,next){

  // this route is never fired 
  console.log('second route')
  res.send('second route')

})
```

The second function is not getting called. Any ideas

Answer (score 4):

In the first middleware function, you're calling `next` with the parameter `'route'`. As stated in the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get), this causes the subsequent callbacks to be bypassed:

> You can provide multiple callback functions that behave just like middleware, except that these callbacks can invoke `next('route')` to bypass the remaining route callback(s).

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to

```
app.get('/foo',function(req,res,next){

  console.log('first route')
  return next();

},function(req,res,next){

  // this route is never fired 
  console.log('second route')
  res.send('second route')

})
```